# Unable to launch hive

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I am not able to launch Hive while following [the getting started procedure](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted)

Here is the error:

```
$ ./hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoopuser/Downloads/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoopuser/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Hive Session ID = 3494229b-6c3c-4c5b-ba62-a82edde75f18
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliSessionState.<init>(CliSessionState.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
```

I believe the problem is coming from the java version, based on other SO questions. But they did not help me.

When I run `java -version`, I get:

```
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

However, when I get my $JAVA_HOME variable, it is correctly set to java 1.8:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

BUT, when I use the alternative command to select my java version, I get the following result:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
[sudo] password for hadoopuser: 
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit 1 : Similar error when running `./beeline -u jdbc:hive2://`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that the binaries for Java 11 are still first in your PATH. Check if the bin folder for Java 11 is appearing first with `echo $PATH`.

If that's the case, a quick fix might just be to prepend the path to the Java 8 bin folder to your `.bashrc` file. Appending something like this might help:

`export PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin:$PATH"`

Then `java -version` should show the right one.

Answer (score 1):

For exactly same problem with Hadoop version 3.3.5 and Hive 3.1.3. on Ubuntu 22.04, I have to install JDK with below command

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

and Then set JAVA_HOME as follows

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
export PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:$PATH"
```

Below option does not fix the issue for me

```
export PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin:$PATH"
```